# play a youtube video with a form

Tags: forms, iframe, video, youtube

I am trying to play a youtube video that a user enters into a form. Specifically a user will paste a youtube video URL into my form, hit submit, and on the next page it will play that video in an iFrame. Does anyone have any idea how to do this? Somehow it needs to convert the YouTube URL (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VIDEO_ID) to the embed URL (http://www.youtube.com/v/VIDEO_ID) and then make that the source of the iFrame on the next page. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Which language can u use ?'php ?

Comment: Yeah, whatever will get the job done.

Comment: I don't even know where to start. I've been reading YouTube's API but I don't think that's the right way to go about it. I was also looking at [this](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Video::Embed), which uses Perl, but I'm not familiar with Perl at all.

Comment: have you tried my code? if so, please consider accepting the answer.

Comment: @Tuga sorry for the late reply, I had to put this on hold for a while. It's not quite working. I just made a test page with exactly that script: http://rickscohen.com/heist/

Comment: please put the code inside of a file named `something.php`, if your code is already inside a php file, your server isn't processing `php` files correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["youtube"]))
{
if(strlen($_POST["youtube"]) == 11)
{
$videoid= $_POST["youtube"];
echo <<< EOF
<iframe frameBorder="no" width="100%" height="100%" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/$videoid" allowfullscreen></iframe>
EOF;
}else{
$yturl = rawurldecode($_POST["youtube"]);
parse_str( parse_url( $yturl, PHP_URL_QUERY ), $yt_array_of_vars );
$videoid= $yt_array_of_vars['v'];
echo <<< EOF
<iframe frameBorder="no" width="100%" height="100%" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/$videoid" allowfullscreen></iframe>
EOF;
}

}else{

$posturl = htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);
echo <<< EOF
<html>
<head>
<style>
    html,body, div, iframe{
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        margin: 0; padding: 0;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="$posturl"> 
<div align="center">
<p> <h3> Type the Youtube URL or VIDEOID</h3></p>
<input type="text" name="youtube" value="">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
EOF;
}
?>
```

Check the YouTube iframe options [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo?csw=1)

If you want the html5 player, append `html5=1`to the iframe `src`, like this:

```
<iframe frameBorder="no" width="100%" height="100%" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/$videoid?html5=1" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```